# Как ввести данные в <input> при помощи Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Есть необходимость залогинится на сайте. Для этого нужно ввести имя пользователя и пароль. Для парсинга использую Jsoup:

```
final Document res = new PageLoader().load(LOGINPAGE);
final Element username = res.getElementById("UserName");
final Element password = res.getElementById("Password");
```

Сами элементы выглядят так:

```
System.out.println(username.toString());
System.out.println(password.toString());

<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" class="std-input full center"> 
<input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" class="std-input full center">
```

Помогите пожалуйста ввести данные. htmlunit в данном случае, к сожалению не применим.

Comment: Это вам не браузер чтобы текст в `input` вводить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий способ:

```
String logonURL = doc.select("form").attr("abs:action");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(logonURL)
            .data("UserName", "логин", "Password", "пароль")
            .post();
```

Для отправки больших форм рекомендую использовать FormElement.

```
// Создаём FormElement, содержащий дефолтовое состояние формы.
FormElement form = (FormElement) doc.select("form").first();
/* Здесь нужно вставить код, редактирующий форму */
// Отправляем форму
doc = form.submit()
            .post();
```